# deque segfault error

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, std

```
struct air_message
{    
    deque<int> path;

    int dest_region;
    int dest_airport;
    int next_region;

    int msg_from;
};
```

I have this structure. And I have this code

```
deque<int> p = graph->get_shortest_path(source_region, dest_region);                    
m->path = p;
```

At this line

```
m->path = p;
```

I am getting a segmentation fault error ('m' is a pointer of the `air_message` structure).

Comment: You didn't allocate the object pointed to by `m` correctly.

Comment: Are you positive that `m` is correctly initialized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to examine the code that allocates `m`. Your problem here isn't with the deque itself, it's because `m` is not a valid pointer.

For example, if the only code you have is:

```
struct air_message *m;
deque<int> p = graph->get_shortest_path (blah, blah);                    
m->path = p;
```

then yes, `m` will not be valid.